# error handle from child async callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
 function main(){
    try {
      subCallbackFunction(1,(err,res) =>{
        if(err){
          throw Error(err);
        }          
      })
    } catch (e) {
      /// Want to handle err from here //////
      console.log("Error handle block",e)
    }
}



////// subCallbackFunction ////
async function subCallbackFunction(arg, callback){
    await waitFor(2000);
    //sending error///
    callback("My error")
}
/// Wait Promise //
const waitFor = (ms) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

/// call main function /////
main();
```

Want to handle the subCallbackFunction callback error inside the catch block of the main function.

It's giving an error

```
(node:1081) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: My error
(node:1081) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1081) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make your main function async and use await for nested async functions:

```
async function main(){
    try {
        await subCallbackFunction(1,(err,res) =>{
            if(err){
                throw Error(err);
            }
        })
    } catch (e) {
        /// Want to handle err from here //////
        console.log("Error handle block",e)
    }
}



////// subCallbackFunction ////
async function subCallbackFunction(arg, callback){
    await waitFor(2000);
    //sending error///
    callback("My error")
}
/// Wait Promise //
const waitFor = (ms) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

/// call main function /////
main();
```

Or:

```
function main() {
    subCallbackFunction(1, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            throw Error(err);
        }
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log("Error handle block", e)
    })
}

////// subCallbackFunction ////
async function subCallbackFunction(arg, callback){
    await waitFor(2000);
    //sending error///
    callback("My error")
}
/// Wait Promise //
const waitFor = (ms) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

/// call main function /////
main();
```